# mod_rewrite link inconsistency

Tags: php, google-chrome, mod-rewrite

I have a navigation list with links that contain the same path.  The links are evaluated with mod_rewrite.  All but the first one work well.  the 1st one (overview) goes to a link that misses the mymathsmatch/ part.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

These are the links:

```
<div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
          <a href="/mymathsmatch/Explorers/percentBusiness/percentStock"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span><br class="hidden-xs"><br class="hidden-xs">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li>
          <a href="/mymathsmatch/Explorers/stockpercent1/percentStock"><span class="menumber">1</span><br class="hidden-xs"><br class="hidden-xs">20 Apr</a>
    </li>
    <li>
          <a href="/mymathsmatch/Explorers/stockpercent2/percentStock"><span class="menumber">2</span><br class="hidden-xs"><br class="hidden-xs">27 Apr</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
          <a href="/mymathsmatch/Explorers/stockpercent3/percentStock"><span class="menumber">3</span><br class="hidden-xs"><br class="hidden-xs">4 May</a>
    </li>
    <li>
          <a href="/mymathsmatch/Explorers/stockmarketnew/percentStock"><span class="menumber">4</span><br class="hidden-xs"><br class="hidden-xs">11 May</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="/mymathsmatch/Explorers/makemoneyStock/percentStock"><span class="menumber">5</span><br class="hidden-xs"><br class="hidden-xs">18 May</a>
    </li></ul><!-- #nav-list -->
</div>
```

Here is the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mymathsmatch/

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ colltemplate.php?MCname=$1&collname=$2&progname=$3
```

Thanks

Comment: just to add to above, I've also added a base tag in the HTML header as follows:

Comment: <base href="/mymathsmatch/"; />

Comment: Also forgot to mention that it is only on Chrome that this seems to be an issue